# Is it possible to define a scope for a non db column

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

We have a method in our model `occurs_on?`

```
Enrollment.first.occurs_on?(Date.current)
```

which returns true if an enrollment falls on a Date (and false if not). Enrollments have a recurring schedule and it's not possible to do a db query for `occurs_on?` without doing calculations in Ruby. It's all working fine but this is throwing off our pagination. Is it possible to define a scope that doesn't depend on a database column? For example something like

```
scope :occurs_today, -> { occurs_on?(Date.current) }
```

I'm hoping it's possible so we can use pagination and also chain the scope, for example

```
Enrollment.active.occurs_today
```

Answer (score 2):

All what Jon wrote is correct, however, `scopes` are basically only class methods on your model class. This means you could replicate a similar behaviour depending on which library you use for pagination.

Example

```rb
class Enrollment
  scope :active -> { where(active: true) }

  def self.occurs_today
    records = select { |record| record.occurs_on?(Date.current) }

    # https://github.com/kaminari/kaminari#paginating-a-generic-array-object
    Kaminari.paginate_array(records, total_count: count)
  end
end

Enrollment.active.occours_today.page(2)
```

This of course has a few limitations

- You still need to load all records from the database and filter them in Ruby. One main benefit of pagination is to load less data so it's not really what you should do.
- The 'scope' does not return an ActiveRecord relationship but e.g. an Array so you have to use the method as the last one because `Enrollment.occurs_today.active` will throw a `undefined method active`.

Answer (score -1):

No, what you're suggesting isn't possible because scopes are just used to modify the SQL query generated by ActiveRecord.

However, you can probably create a scope that achieves what you're looking for. Whilst you may not be familiar/comfortable with it, and it will likely require you to write code specific to your DB of choice, you can almost certainly replicate the logic you require for identifying whether your `Enrollment` occurs on a specific date within your DB query.

Answer (score -1):

This seems to work. I'm sure it's inefficient but it's giving us correct results *and* pagination works on this

```
scope :occurs_today, -> { where(id: all.select { |s| s.occurs_on?(Date.current) }.map(&:id)) }
```

Comment: FYI: You can use `pluck` on an `Enumerable` like `all.select { |s| s.occurs_on?(Date.current) }.pluck(:id)`.

Comment: Yeah the disadvantage is that you basically select twice from the database. Depending on the pagination library you could get rid of the second database call with the solution I provided. If you need to return an ActiveRecord Relationship than yours is a clever solution,

Comment: `scope :occurs_today, -> { where(id: all.select { |s| s.occurs_on?(Date.current) }.pluck(:id) }` unless we see a better/easier solution than this we're going with this :)