# Is it possible to specify order of a chained scope query

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I'm currently doing a chained scope query like this

```
Enrollment.active.occurs_today
```

Is it possible to order the query so that `.active` is queried before `.occurs_today` and prevent lazy loading? Something similar to below hopefully

```
Enrollment.active.eval.occurs_today
```

Answer (score 0):

What's not always appreciated is that the order of chained scope doesn't really matter. The chained scopes are building a single query that includes all the conditions, and then when you action the query (by requesting records or a count, for example) at that point the records are retrieved using the combined conditions.

The exception is the rails console, where each scope is executed as it's entered.

if you have pseudo-scope (something that does a query that returns `id` and then queries on that) you could implement it as a class method and arrange to pass into the class method other scopes as arguments to execute them first.  A possible implementation might be...

```
def self.occurs_today(*scopes)
  result = scopes.inject(all) {|relation, scope| relation.send(scope)}    
  where(id: result.select { |s| s.occurs_on?(Date.current) }.map(&:id))
end
```

You could then do

```
Enrollment.occurs_today(:active)
```

or several scopes

```
Enrollment.occurs_today(:active, :priority)
```

In both cases, the `select` will be performed on the already scoped relation.

alternatively, I think you could see an improvement in performance (and automatic recognition of scope order) just by changing your existing `occurs_today` scope.

Instead of selecting on all records...

```
scope :occurs_today, -> { where(id: all.select { |s| s.occurs_on?(Date.current) }.pluck(:id) }
```

...select on only the currently scoped records...

```
scope :occurs_today, -> { where(id: select { |s| s.occurs_on?(Date.current) }.pluck(:id) }
```

Comment: Yes, I've never had to worry about the order before. We're having to do a [pretty inefficient] non db column scope query where it seems to matter unfortunately https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63927562/is-it-possible-to-define-a-scope-for-a-non-db-column/63928289

Comment: Ah, I see that now.  Is the `occurs_today method just checking today's date is between a start and end date or is it more complex?  Wondering if it could be a DB method?

Comment: You can pass an active record relation into a class method... given that it should be possible to chain it into a specific order.

Comment: User Enrollments have a recurring schedule, in different timezones, often with holidays etc. It would be complex to make it a db method. Could you let me know what you mean by "pass an active record relation into a class method"

Comment: Answer edited to illustrate.  But I think a small change to the `occurs_today` scope would fix your issue... see the last four lines of my answer.